# Как использовать SPRITE?

Tags: html, спрайт, css

Я новичок в общения с sprite. Есть sprite в формате png (width: 100px; height: 133px), в нем расположены три рисунка. Как мне задействовать один из них, но чтоб остальных двух рисунков не было видно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно осуществить вот по такому принципу:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sprite"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .sprite {
    background: url('адрес_Вашей_картинки') no-repeat область спрайта(Например: -11px -51px); 
    width: ширина;
    height: высота;
    }
```

Есть такой сервис, называется он spritecow, он автоматически выдает координаты спрайта, Вам только необходимо загрузить картинку и выделить область. [Ссылка](http://www.spritecow.com/)

Comment: Спасибо вам! Я вчера ночью разобрался:)!

Comment: За http://www.spritecow.com/ отдельное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

[с помощью css: background-position,](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position)